# Inputting responses to single-word requests

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exception to 30 character minimum for answers](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/exception-to-30-character-minimum-for-answers)

a) If a question is clearly a 'single-word request', shouldn't it be possible to click submit with just one word in the text box - even if there are fewer than 23 characters in the response ?

Thanks for any pointers on how this can be done, or why it shouldn't be.

b) If this question has already been asked, can someone direct me to the archive so I can look at the response/s?